# How to block (or redirect) external image source?

Tags: media

Users can add images to content. They're supposed to be uploading them to the site, but occasionally people will reference an image hosted elsewhere in the src='...'.

What is the best way to prevent these images from working (or even better, redirecting to a "This image is blocked" image)? I imagined using a hook of some sort to modify the content, or possibly a module that adds a filter to weed out these images. But it seems like a situation I could be overthinking.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I presume you are allowing the uploading and embedding of images via the WYSIWYG. That being the case you need to write a text filter and apply it to the text format the users are allowed to use (Filtered HTML for example). 
http://local.example.com/admin/config/content/formats/filtered_html

Have a look at the [Examples module](https://drupal.org/project/examples) for how to do that.

```
filter_example  Defining an input filter
```

If you're not allowing them to upload and embed via the WYSIWYG (but uploading via a field for example) you could simply remove `img` from the permitted tags in your **Limit allowed HTML tags** filter.

Comment: Users are allowed to upload files via WYSIWYG, so your solution makes sense to me. Thanks!